# Can I use ProcessExplorer to trace the parameters of future running process?

Tags: windows-10, process, sysinternals

I would like be able to trace all calls to `MSBuild.exe` with its parameters. It seems I should be using sysinternals Process Explorer. I'm lost how I can accomplish this or if I should be doing something else.

Important that I trying to trace any calls to MSBuild.exe and not one particular running process.

Comment: Take a look at Process Monitor instead: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon , also from SysInternals.

Comment: I myself would make a stub/fake msbuild.exe for this purpose from my own code.  My copy would report it's command line "somewhere" and then call the original version with the command line passed to it.  This is much simpler to do than what you are trying to do (IMHO) and would only need a minimum amount of code to accomplish in just about any language.